# HTC Desire S - UK Orange Stuck on HTC Boot logo

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, boot-loop, htc

My old HTC Desire S had Android 2.x installed and I wanted to update it to 4.x . I followed the instructions at htc.com to unlock the boot-loader, which seemed to work and after installing it, I can now boot the phone into ClockworkMod Recovery v5.0.2.0.

The problem I'm facing is, no matter what ROM I try and flash, the phone reboots to just the HTC boot logo and I have to pull the battery out to get it to boot back into Recovery. The device is in the S-ON state.

Is there something I've missed, or something specific I should be doing? Or some specific ROM I should be using?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the previous ROM ? Tell me if it works, and I'll guide you further.

Comment: Do you have a NANDroid backup or anything ? 
Try this : 
Open an ADB window. 
Connect your phone using a data cable to the PC. 
Type adb get-state. 
Tell me the result. 
If you don't know what ADB (PC) is, just Google it.

Comment: Hi, I made the rookie mistake of not making a backup. :eek I figured with all the rooms available and it being such an old device it'd be simple.

Comment: adb get-state returns 'recovery' (To get it to show up in adb devices I had to select recovery in the boot menu)

Comment: What is the state of the device while in boot logo ?

Comment: It wouldn't show up as a device in adb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23044/discussion-between-rjt-rockx-and-darren).

Comment: Answered in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method we followed :

1. Update the recovery to a newer version (We used TWRP 2.8)
2. Install a new ROM. (We installed CyanogenMod 12.1 Lollipop)
3. Extract that ROM and flash the boot.img manually (using ADB and Fastboot)
4. Boot into the ROM.

Done !

Note : Always remember to take a NANDroid backup before you install anything to your phone !

Comment: For the original discussion, please refer http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23044/discussion-between-rjt-rockx-and-darren

Comment: @Darren, Enjoy a sweet new take on Android : http://www.android.com/versions/lollipop-5-0/

Comment: `Note : Always remember to take a NANDroid backup before you install anything to your phone !` -- So you're telling me that if I want to install [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage)  <200KB completely harmless app, I'll have to resort to >1GB NANDroid backup. Not fair. :D  How about an [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/106127/edit)?